# Hosting flutter web application on firebase

Tags: flutter, dart

I was hosting a Flutter Web project using Firebase Hosting.

I did firebase init then firebase deploy but my hosted website looks like this:

https://employee-profile-details.web.app/#/

please help me to solve the issue

please help me to solve the issue

Comment: kindly share your actual design . What are u missing ?

Comment: Is there any errors? I could see the site after a while. right click in your browser and use inspect to see the console.

Answer (score 0):

Error could be due to an `expanded` or `flexible` widget.
try removing the **expanded** or **flexible** containers from the code.

can you share code for more reference?